# Sum rows in column with specific text IF corresponding row in different column has specific text

Tags: excel, text, sum

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

```
     A       B       C
1  CLD     TEXT   Valid
2  CLD     TEXT   Expired
3  CLA     TEXT   Valid
4  CLA     TEXT   Expired
5  CPI     TEXT   Valid
6  CLD     TEXT   Valid
```

I would like to count the number of rows in column A that have the same text (e.g. `CLD`) where the text for the same row in column C = `Valid` and display that counted value elsewhere in the spreadsheet.

Given the data above, I would expect a count of `CLD` in column A to return a value of `2`, as there are only two `CLD` rows with corresponding `Valid` in column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you would be looking for something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"Valid",A:A,"CLD")
```

It should count instances based in multiple criteria (in this case just the two).